# Doubly Linked List Remove Method

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Trying to implement a method that removes a node at the specified index and returns its data element. Taking a beginner online course and I'm not sure how to return the data type E. Sorry if my code is atrocious.

```
public class MyLinkedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    LLNode<E> head;
    LLNode<E> tail;
    int size;

    /** Create a new empty LinkedList */
    public MyLinkedList() {
        size = 0;
        head = new LLNode<E>(null); 
        tail = new LLNode<E>(null);
        head.next = tail;
        tail.prev = head;

    public E remove(int index) 
    {
        int ithNode = 1; //tracks node path location
        LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>(null);

        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        if (index == 1) {
            newNode = head.next;
            head.next = null;
            head.prev = null;
        } else {
            while (ithNode != index) {
                head = head.next;
                ithNode++;
            }
            if (head.next == null) {
                head.prev.next = null;
                head.prev = null;
            } else {
                head.prev.next = head.next;
                head.next.prev = head.prev;
            }
        }
    }

}

class LLNode<E> 
{
    LLNode<E> prev;
    LLNode<E> next;
    E data;

//Not sure if I should create another constructor here 
    public LLNode(E e) 
    {
        this.data = e;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you remove something, why not return the node that you removed, or simply not returning anything

Comment: `if (index < 0 || index > size())` should be `if (index < 0 || index >= size())` or preferably `if (!(index >= 0 && index < size()))` in the 4th line of remove method.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your assignment.  Why invent your own class?  java.util.LinkedList is bidirectional, and implements a remove() method which returns the element removed.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, E is a placeholder for whatever data-type will got into the LinkedList. You would return the data as you would any other element. My suggestion is once you get to the element to remove, save the data that is there, set the new next and previous references, then return the data. Example:

```
E returnData = head.data;
//set references
return returnData;
```